# How to host nextjs project with basePath in firebase? I am facing 404 index.html not found

Tags: firebase, next.js

I have a `basePath` in nextjs config. When I setup the `basePath` it is working fine on local. But when I deploy the project in firebase I am getting 404 index.html not found. Below is my firebase.json config:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-east1"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There should be enough information in the question that anyone can use to duplicate the result.  That means providing a [minimal complete reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example) with all the code, configuration, and instructions that you use to make this happen.